# Showing labels only at edge of grouped PGF plots

Tags: pgfplots, labels

The options `xlabels at` and `ylabels at` in PGFplots' grouped plots library are supposed to show axis labels only at the corresponding sides of the complete set of plots, but they seem to have no effect. Am I doing something wrong in this example, or is this a bug?

```
\documentclass{standalone}
\usepackage{pgfplots}
\usepgfplotslibrary{groupplots}
\pgfplotsset{compat=1.10}
\begin{document}
 \begin{tikzpicture}
  \begin{groupplot}[group style={group size=2 by 2,ylabels at=edge left,xlabels at=edge bottom}]
   \nextgroupplot[xlabel=a,ylabel=b]
   \addplot {x};
   \nextgroupplot[xlabel=foo,ylabel=b]
   \addplot {x};
   \nextgroupplot[xlabel=a,ylabel=fdsio]
   \addplot {x};
   \nextgroupplot[xlabel=foo,ylabel=fdsio]
   \addplot {x};
  \end{groupplot}
 \end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

which produces

[image: output]

but that's not what I want. Only the labels along the bottom and left edges should appear.

I seem to remember this working in the past, so perhaps something changed in PGFplots 1.10?

Comment: I didn't try but aren't the labels supposed to be the same then if they could be omitted? Eg what happens if all x-axis are yah and all y-axis fdsio?

Answer (score 2):

On pgfplots version 1.10 manual, section 5.7, page 384, It introduces an equivalent plot without using `groupplots` library. With that said, This solution yields an alternative where only the labels along the bottom and left edges appear.

[image]

Code

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{pgfplots}
\usepgfplotslibrary{groupplots}
\pgfplotsset{compat=1.10}
\begin{document}
\begin{tikzpicture}
\begin{axis}[name=plot1,ylabel=b]
   \addplot {x};
\end{axis}
\begin{axis}[name=plot2,at={($(plot1.east)+(1cm,0)$)},anchor=west]
   \addplot {x};
\end{axis}
\begin{axis}[name=plot3,at={($(plot1.south)-(0,1cm)$)},anchor=north,xlabel=a,ylabel=fdsio]
   \addplot {x};
\end{axis}
\begin{axis}[name=plot4,at={($(plot2.south)-(0,1cm)$)},anchor=north,xlabel=foo]
   \addplot {x};
\end{axis}
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

Answer (score 1):

Based on my comment, putting x and ylabels in each plot make no sense. So based on the manual, the good way is to put it in the groupplot options directly. Also, you had a small mistake, as `xlabels at` can not have `edge left` as option.

See http://pgfplots.sourceforge.net/pgfplots.pdf page 383 onwards.

```
\documentclass{standalone}
\usepackage{pgfplots}
\usepgfplotslibrary{groupplots}
\pgfplotsset{compat=1.10}
\begin{document}
 \begin{tikzpicture}
  \begin{groupplot}[group style={group size=2 by 2,ylabels at=edge left,xlabels at=edge bottom}, xlabel=bar, ylabel=toto]
   \nextgroupplot
   \addplot {x};
   \nextgroupplot
   \addplot {x};
   \nextgroupplot
   \addplot {x};
   \nextgroupplot
   \addplot {x};
  \end{groupplot}
 \end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: Thanks for pointing out the mistake; I fixed it. My issue is that the plots in the first row have a different y axis label from the plots in the second row. I've edited the question to reflect this. As far as I know, there is no way to specify a label for selected plots in the `groupplot` options, so this solution doesn't work for me. (I have other instances where the plots all have the same label and in those cases, this is exactly what I do.)

Comment: @DavidZ I see your point. I guess this is so "specific" that it needs some macro to do if you want it to be automatic... Or you can use two groupplots and shift them into position but that seems cumbersome.

Answer (score 1):

I had the same problem and just found a workaround: 
just leave out the global labels and define them only for those plots inside the groupplot that are at the edges.

```
\documentclass{standalone}
\usepackage{pgfplots}
\usepgfplotslibrary{groupplots}
\pgfplotsset{compat=1.10}
\begin{document}
 \begin{tikzpicture}
  \begin{groupplot}[group style={group size=2 by 2}]
   \nextgroupplot[ylabel=b]
   \addplot {x};
   \nextgroupplot[]
   \addplot {x};
   \nextgroupplot[xlabel=a,ylabel=fdsio]
   \addplot {x};
   \nextgroupplot[xlabel=foo]
   \addplot {x};
  \end{groupplot}
 \end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```